# Clear text field with own class on dropdown change value JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like that on CHANGED VALUE in each select, all own grouped textboxes by relevant class comes to blank value
I tried with this simple code, but no success.
Please help me and many thanks in advance.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

 $("#FormPallet" + $(this).val()).on("change", function () {
   $(".FormCollo" + $(this).val()).val("");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="content">
            <p>
                <label> Dropdown :</label>
                <select id="FormPallet1">
                    <option value="1">value_1</option>
                    <option value="2">value_2</option>

                </select>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label>Name : </label>
                <input class="FormCollo1" type="text" />
            </p>
            <p>
                <label>Reference ID : </label>
                <input class="FormCollo1" type="text" />
            </p>
            <p>
                <label>Amount : </label>
                <input class="FormCollo1" type="text" />
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <p style="color: red;">second block</p>
    <br />
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="content">
            <p>
                <label> Dropdown :</label>
                <select id="FormPallet2">
                    <option value="1">value_1</option>
                    <option value="2">value_2</option>
                </select>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label>Name : </label>
                <input class="FormCollo2" type="text" />
            </p>
            <p>
                <label>Reference ID : </label>
                <input class="FormCollo2" type="text" />
            </p>
            <p>
                <label>Amount : </label>
                <input class="FormCollo2" type="text" />
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Your `$(this).val()` in `$("#FormPallet" + $(this).val()).on` not defined, so the listener not work

Answer (score 0):

You can't access `$this` without reference to any element.So `$(this).val()` in `$("#FormPallet" + $(this).val()).on` will be not defined,

This way it will work

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

 $("#FormPallet1,#FormPallet2").on("change", function () {
   $(".FormCollo" + $(this).val()).val("");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="content">
            <p>
                <label> Dropdown :</label>
                <select id="FormPallet1">
                    <option value="1">value_1</option>
                    <option value="2">value_2</option>

                </select>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label>Name : </label>
                <input class="FormCollo1" type="text" />
            </p>
            <p>
                <label>Reference ID : </label>
                <input class="FormCollo1" type="text" />
            </p>
            <p>
                <label>Amount : </label>
                <input class="FormCollo1" type="text" />
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <p style="color: red;">second block</p>
    <br />
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="content">
            <p>
                <label> Dropdown :</label>
                <select id="FormPallet2">
                    <option value="1">value_1</option>
                    <option value="2">value_2</option>
                </select>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label>Name : </label>
                <input class="FormCollo2" type="text" />
            </p>
            <p>
                <label>Reference ID : </label>
                <input class="FormCollo2" type="text" />
            </p>
            <p>
                <label>Amount : </label>
                <input class="FormCollo2" type="text" />
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple things I see here...

First, your first use of `$(this).val()` doesn't really do anything, because you're in the context of the `document.ready` handler which doesn't *have* a value.  It sounds like what you want is to target all `select` elements which *start with* a given string in their `id`.  Which would be something like this:

```
$("[id^=FormPallet]").on("change", function () {
    //...
});
```

From there, you don't want to base the selection of the items to empty on the *value* of the `select`, but rather on the *location in the DOM* of the `select`.  Otherwise, selecting "2" in the first `select` will result in the second form being emptied.

From the "current" element, navigate up to a common parent element and then find the target elements therein.  Something like this:

```
$(this).closest('div').find('input').val('');
```

This would find all the `input` elements in the most immediate containing `div` element.  [Here's a running example](https://jsfiddle.net/9656hn33/).

---

Side note: You're re-using the same `id` values in your HTML.  While in this particular case the JavaScript code isn't relying on that and *should* still work, that's still something you're going to want to fix.  Invalid HTML leads to undefined JavaScript behavior.